# Prove this inequality $\sum _{cyc}a^3+4\left(\sum _{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}\right)\ge 9$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

> Let $a>0$, $b>0$ and $c>0$ such that $abc=1$. Prove that: $$a^3+b^3+c^3+4\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{bc}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{ca}{c^2+a^2}\right)\ge 9.$$

---

$$L.H.S=a^3+b^3+c^3+4\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{bc}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{ca}{c^2+a^2}\right)\ge 9$$

$$\ge 3+4\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{bc}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{ca}{c^2+a^2}\right)$$

Need to prove $$3+4\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{bc}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{ca}{c^2+a^2}\right)\ge 9$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{bc}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{ca}{c^2+a^2}\ge \frac{3}{2}$$

This inequality is homogeneous, we assume that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, and need to prove 
$$\frac{1}{3c-c^3}+\frac{1}{3a-a^3}+\frac{1}{3b-b^3}\ge \frac{3}{2}$$

We have inequality $$\frac{1}{3a-a^3}\ge \frac{3}{8}a^2+\frac{1}{8}(*)$$

$$\Rightarrow LHS\ge \frac{3}{8}\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)+\frac{1}{8}.3=\frac{3}{2}$$

How to prove (*) ? $\Leftrightarrow \frac{\left(a-1\right)\left(3a^4+3a^3-5a^2-5a-8\right)}{8\left(3a-a^3\right)}\ge 0$ Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is wrong because the inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{3}{2}$ is wrong.

Try $b=c\rightarrow0^+$.

SOS helps.

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Hence, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$b^2\sum_{cyc}\left(a^3+\frac{4ab}{a^2+b^2}-3\right)=b^2\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^3-abc)-2\sum_{cyc}\left(1-\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}\right)\right)=$$
$$=b^2\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-\frac{2}{a^2+b^2}\right)=\frac{b^2}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2((a+b+c)(a^2+b^2)-4abc)}{a^2+b^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{b^2}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2((a+b+c)2ab-4abc)}{a^2+b^2}=b^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2ab(a+b-c)}{a^2+b^2}\geq$$
$$\geq \frac{b^2(a-c)^2ac(a+c-b)}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{b^2(b-c)^2bc(b+c-a)}{b^2+c^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{a^2(b-c)^2ac(a-b)}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{b^2(b-c)^2bc(b-a)}{b^2+c^2}=$$
$$=\frac{abc^3(a+b)(b-c)^2(a-b)^2}{(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)}\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Nice, I can get non-negative SOS without assuming but ugly.

Answer (score 1):

We can factorize
\begin{align} a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc &= (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc) \\
&= \frac{a+b+c}{2}[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2] \end{align}
and write
$$\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2} = 1-\frac{(a-b)^2}{a^2+b^2} $$
(similarly with the other terms), to rewrite, with $abc=1$,
\begin{align} & a^3+b^3+c^3+4\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{ac}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{bc}{b^2+c^2}\right) \\
&=(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc) + 2\left[\left(\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}-1\right)+\left(\frac{2ac}{a^2+c^2}-1\right)+\left(\frac{2bc}{b^2+c^2}-1\right)\right]\\
&+3abc+2+2+2 \\
&=\frac{a+b+c}{2}[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2]-2\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{(a-c)^2}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{b^2+c^2}\right)+9.
\end{align}
It thus suffices to show that
\begin{align}&\frac{a+b+c}{2}[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2]\\
&\ge\frac{2}{a^2+b^2}(a-b)^2+\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}(a-c)^2+\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}(b-c)^2 \end{align}
when $abc=1$.

Without loss of generality, suppose $a\ge b\ge c$. Then $(a-c)^2\ge (b-c)^2$, while $\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}\le\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}$. By the rearrangement inequality, we have
$$\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}(a-c)^2+\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}(b-c)^2\le\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}(a-c)^2+\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}(b-c)^2.$$
Thus $\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}(a-c)^2+\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}(b-c)^2$ is also less than or equal to its average with $\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}(a-c)^2+\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}(b-c)^2$, i.e.
$$\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}(a-c)^2+\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}(b-c)^2\le\left(\frac{1}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\right)[(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2].$$
We have, by AM-GM,
$$a^2+c^2\ge 2ac = \frac{2}{b},$$
and similarly $b^2+c^2\ge\frac{2}{a}$, so $\frac{1}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\le \frac{b}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\le\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. It follows that
\begin{align}\frac{a+b+c}{2}[(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2]&\ge\left(\frac{1}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\right)[(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2]\\
&\ge\frac{2}{a^2+c^2}(a-c)^2+\frac{2}{b^2+c^2}(b-c)^2.
\end{align}
Similarly, $\frac{2}{a^2+b^2}\le c$, which is certainly less than $\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ since in fact $c\le\frac{a+b+c}{3}$, so
$$\frac{a+b+c}{2}(a-b)^2\ge\frac{2}{a^2+b^2}(a-b)^2.$$
Adding the two inequalities gives the desired inequality.